# Image Tiling with pure CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

I am trying to tile images in a grid-like system where there is no spacing between any of them.  Is it possible to do without javascript if you can't control the order of the images in the DOM?

You obviously can't just float the containers because there will be gaps **if your images are not all the same size.**

http://jsfiddle.net/bzCNb/3/

```
.wrapper
{
    width:400px;
}

/* One grid unit */
.box1
{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

/* 2x bigger than a box1, takes up 4 grid units */
.box4
{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

The first three rows behave properly because of the order of the elements in the DOM.

**I'm guessing its not possible without javascript.  Hopefully I am wrong. =)**

Comment: I don't think it is possible without javascript. Though only thing I can think of is maybe using the CSS3 multiple background image property on a single container.

Comment: Seems to me that all the rows don't have gaps, but I don't know if it's the fact that I'm using Chrome.

Comment: afaik, you have to use javascript (something like masonry) to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to masonry.  I implemented it for now. Seems like it has a few bugs but I'm sure I can get them ironed out.

Comment: You and me both wish this were possible in CSS, but as of yet, I have not found a way to do it.

Comment: Its JS, but, Isotope is the way to go: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Are you in control of the images coming in and their order?  Will this fluctuate?

Comment: Not in control, yes they will fluctuate.

Answer (score 4):

You could use column-count CSS3 property to make a grid and have the images fit in like in the following tutorial. http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/